# Where can I find the Fat Man in Fallout New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I have tons of mini nukes. The only problem is that the only weapon that shoots mini nukes is the Fat Man. I've seen it a few places and and never had the caps to buy it. Is there a place in Fallout New Vegas where I can get it for a low price or free?

Answer (score 7):

Well, merchants don't charge different prices, so the only way to lower the price of an item is to increase your Barter skill.

You can find Fat Men in the following locations ([source](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fat_Man_%28Fallout:_New_Vegas%29#Locations)):

- Cottonwood crater - On the body of a dead prospector.
- Quarry Junction - Lying near the edge of a radioactive pool to the west of the quarry. On this [map](http://planetfallout.gamespy.com/maps/3/Fallout-New-Vegas) you can select weapons>big guns and you will see 3 markers on the map,one of them is the location for the fat man(Quarry).
- Nopah cave - On the corpse of a super mutant master.
- On the body of a super mutant master near a cazador nest directly south of Jacobstown.
- The Fort - At high player levels one can be found on a legionary blacksmith

Be aware that most of these locations are dangerous for a low level character.

Comment: The Gun Runners Arsenal DLC also added a unique variant, named Esther.  It's not cheap, but I made a tonne of money by playing through Lonesome Road and selling everything I picked up everytime I hit a Commissary.  Made buying Esther simple.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen one on the backs of a couple boomers walking around the base.  But you would have to kill them to get it.

Answer (score 0):

The Brotherhood of Steel has a shop in their bunker that sells the Fat Man for 1810 caps. They also have a gatling laser, gauss rifle, grenade machinegun, and other high power weapons for the best prices you'll find.